# React FullCalendar not showing multiday events for the whole duration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I am trying to show events that is more than 1 day in FullCalendar 'AllDay' field. But it is not working properly for example, it is only showing on first day of the event even though it is supposed to show for 3 days span.
[image: picture attached for reference]

Below is the code I've tried:

```
function EventMount(info) {  
  let title                  = info.el.getElementsByClassName('fc-event-title')  
  const description          = info.event?.extendedProps?.description   

  const timetableType        = String(GetValue(description,"Timetable Type:").replace(/\s+/g, ""));
  const isEvent               = timetableType ==="" ? true: false;
  let eventName, room, heading, type, staff;      
  const start = moment(info.event.start);
  const end = moment(info.event.end); 
  let diff = end.diff(start, 'days');
  
  if (isEvent) {
    moduleName  = GetValue(description, "Event:", isEvent); 
    room        = GetValue(description, "Room:", isEvent); 

    // Check if the event spans multiple days

    if (diff > 1) {
      info.event.setAllDay(true); 
  
    } 

  } else {
    eventName = GetValue(description, "Event:");
    room = GetValue(description, "Room:");
    heading = GetValue(description, "Title:"); 
    type = GetValue(description, "Type:");
    staff = GetValue(description, "Staff:");
  }
```

Comment: Please provide sample event data for this event, in JSON format. And ensure we have a [mre] of the issue in general, please. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the JSON data:

{
   "event_name": "Event No 1",
   "date": "2023-05-03",
   "location": "Online",
   "site": "Online",
   "start_date_time": {
      "date": "2023-05-03",
      "time": "09:30",
   },
   "end_date_time": {
      "date": "2023-05-06",
      "time": "09:30",
   }
}

Comment: Fullcalendar can't parse that format by default. So how are you passing it to the calendar? Are you writing some extra code to change the format so those dates are placed into the correct fields before giving it to Fullcalendar? If so, please show that code. P.s. please always [edit] your question when you have code and clarifications to give to us. Code in comments is not always easy to read and also it becomes disconnected from the context of the question in many cases. Thanks.